# Strong duality of SDPs

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

On pp. 654 of Boyd's book, it is claimed that strong duality holds between the SDPs B.2 and B.3 (at the bottom of this page). Does it require additional assumption that one of them is strictly feasible (or it is already implied in the problem)? Thanks.

Comment: It requires that slater constraint qualification satisfied. So, it must be strictly feasible.

Comment: so it needs extra qualification condition that is not stated in the book, right?

Comment: No, it is stated on the next page.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot get the strict feasibility of (B.2) after reading the next page on S-procedure. Can you help elaborate a little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: In the first paragraph at page 654, it is stated that "The first result is that strong duality holds for problem (B.1) and its Lagrange
dual (B.2), provided Slater’s constraint qualification is satisfied,"

Comment: Oh, I guess perhaps I did not make my question very clear. I am puzzled about the strong duality between (B.2) and (B.3), as stated on the bottom of page 654 "with strong duality between the dual SPDs (B.2) and (B.3)". For the strong duality between (B.1) and (B.2), I understand that it holds provided the Slater’s constraint qualification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrangian for B.2, is 
$L(\lambda,\gamma,\eta,\Big[\begin{matrix}X &x\\x^T&y \end{matrix}\Big])=-\gamma-<\Big[\begin{matrix}X &x\\x^T&y \end{matrix}\Big],\Big[\begin{matrix}A_0+\lambda*A_1 &b_0+\lambda b_1\\(b_0+\lambda b_1)^T&c_0+\lambda c_1-\gamma \end{matrix}\Big]>-\eta \lambda$

or

$L(\lambda,\gamma,\eta,\Big[\begin{matrix}X &x\\x^T&y \end{matrix}\Big])=-\gamma(y-1)-\Big(<A_0,X>+2 b_0^T x +c_0\Big)-\Big(<A_1,X>+2 b_1^T x + c_1+\eta \Big)\lambda$

In order for this problem to be feasible and bounded, we must have

$<A_1,X>+2 b_1^T x + c_1+\eta =0$ and $y-1=0$.

And you reach the dual.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed derivation. You can also reach the dual by absorbing the constrain $\lambda \ge 0$ to the LMI and then applying the result in Example 5.11 Lagrange dual of semidefinite problems (pp. 265). My question is actually not the derivation of dual problem itself, but instead the Slater’s condition for strong duality between (B.2) and (B.3). Is (B.2) strictly feasible? Thanks.